# pyinstaller worked yesterday and now it says 'not found'

Tags: python, pip, wxpython, pyinstaller

Yesterday pip and pyinstaller were working, today not.
Using python3 (3.11) on mac os.

```
pyinstaller no longer present in /usr/local/bin.
pip in my /usr/local/bin gives:
/usr/local/bin/pip: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
python3 is present in in /usr/local/bin and works:
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  70 Aug 10 13:58 python3 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/python3
```

Not sure what caused this problem. I had been using python3 in bash via aliases:

```
alias pm='python3 -m $@'
alias py='python3 $@'
```

Yesterday I build a wxpython mac app (on windows too) using pyinstaller.
Today I seem to have python vs python3 problems.
I do not grok "virtual" python.

```
python3 -m pyinstaller
/usr/local/bin/python3: No module named pyinstaller
```

I looked up python va python3 on mac os but was afraid to mess with anything.
I used diskutil First Aid to check for disk errors.
I can run pip like this:

```
python3 -m pip install pyinstaller
Requirement already satisfied: pyinstaller in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages (5.13.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=42.0.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from pyinstaller) (65.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: altgraph in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from pyinstaller) (0.17.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyinstaller-hooks-contrib>=2021.4 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from pyinstaller) (2023.6)
Requirement already satisfied: macholib>=1.8 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from pyinstaller) (1.16.2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem with a PATH correction in my .bash_profile.
Sorry for the bother!

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.11
# The original version is saved in .profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```